# why this addEventListener('click', function) needs two clicks instead of one?

Tags: javascript

I have a div where the css style `display: none` is applied to. What I'm trying to achieve is a one click to change it to `display: block`. Right now, I can't grasp why, but it requires two clicks. Below is the Javascript for it:

```
    var block = document.getElementById('block');
    function switchBlock() {
    block.style.display == "none" ? block.style.display = "block" : block.style.display = "none";
}
    block.addEventListener('click', switchBlock);
```

Comment: why are you adding the listener on first ?

Comment: aside from that the display variable gets initialized as an empty string so turning the if around should fix your problem

Comment: `console.log(blockOne.style.display)`

Comment: `blockOne.style.display == "none"` isn't true, because unless you set it via script, the initial value is going to be `""`. If you want the current style, you need to use `getComputedStyle()`. You can also turn the logic around: `blockOne.style.display == "block" ? blockOne.style.display = "none" : blockOne.style.display = "block";` (rule of thumb: *always* use `console.log` to make sure variables actually have the values you assume they have)

Comment: `getComputedStyle(blockOne).display == "none" ? blockOne.style.display = "block" : blockOne.style.display = "none";`

Comment: toggling a class would be so much easier....

Comment: Another useful lesson here is that one should always store the app state in variables, and never rely on the DOM.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you don't use same var name in your code, don't understand event how it could work on a second click

**EDIT :** This is because element.style != computed style.

```js
var block = document.getElementById('block');
var switcher = document.getElementById('switcher');

function switchBlock() {
  window.getComputedStyle(block).getPropertyValue('display') == "none" ? block.style.display = "block" : block.style.display = "none";
}

switcher.addEventListener('click', switchBlock);
```

```css
#block {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<button id="switcher">click-me</button>
<div id="block">
<span>some text</span>
</div>
```

Comment: @ChrisG i will update but this doesn't change anything